# Async call in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am calling this 2 function 
    this.fetchTables();
    this.fetchAllTables(); in contructor of demo.ts file in Angular.

Both are get api call. Out of these two calls 1 call is failing everytime. Sometime I get result for fetchTables. Sometimes I get result for fetchallTables.

```
      constructor(private api:BackendApiService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private utills:CommonUtillsService, private router: Router) {
            // reload or refresh page on active click
            this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() { return false; }; 
this.fetchTables();
    this.fetchAllTables();

           }

           fetchTables() {
            this.api.getTableAccess().subscribe(data => {
              this.spinner.hide();
              console.log('Data to get tables', data);
              if(data) {
                this.data = data.body.entities;
                this.showNoTableRecordList = false;
              }
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              if (err.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = Constants.GANDALF_HOST;
              }
              this.spinner.hide();
              if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                //A client-side or network error occurred.
                toast(Constants.TOAST_PREFIX+Constants.SOMETHING_WRONG, Constants.TOAST_DURATION);
              } else {
                //Backend returns unsuccessful response codes such as 404, 500 etc.
                toast(Constants.TOAST_PREFIX+Constants.SOMETHING_WRONG, Constants.TOAST_DURATION);
              }
            });
           }

          fetchAllTables() {
            this.api.getAllTable().subscribe(data => {
                this.spinner.hide();
                if(data) {
                  this.allTables = data.body;
                  this.showNoTableRecordList = false;
                } else {
                  this.showNoTableRecordList = true;
                }
              },
              (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (err.status == 401) {
                  window.location.href = Constants.GANDALF_HOST;
                }
                this.spinner.hide();
                if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                  //A client-side or network error occurred.
                  toast(Constants.TOAST_PREFIX+Constants.SOMETHING_WRONG, Constants.TOAST_DURATION);
                } else {
                  //Backend returns unsuccessful response codes such as 404, 500 etc.
                  toast(Constants.TOAST_PREFIX+Constants.SOMETHING_WRONG, Constants.TOAST_DURATION);
                }
              });
          }
```

Comment: can you share more information on the failure... what does the error object return on both of these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn‘t subsribe within both observables but rather combine both observables using RxJS. There are a couple of methods how you can combine them: one would be combineLatest which emits if every child emitted once and then once on child emits again. Here is the documentation on all combining operators: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/

To execute something when one observable emits you could use the tap operator if you don‘t want to do everything that is within your subscriptions in one single subscription of your combined observable

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that subscribe of both these observables has some error in it (I can't identify due to partial file being shared here). So, whenever one of the request is completed, it's subscribe is executed which throws an error and hence prevents the second subscribe from running.

I might be wrong but I'll need more details on your error to confirm. Also, as @Erbsenkoenig mentioned, if you're planning on doing two calls together, I'd recommend using concatMap or mergeMap or something similar.